# How can I classify the following conditional sentences?

Tags: clauses, conditionals

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veTo6eWJQrM). It classifies conditionals as follows:

[image]

I see that these variations are missing:

1. (Present → Past) *If I say something, I destroyed everything.*
2. (Present Perfect → Present Perfect) *If I have done it, I have done it for you.*
3. (Present Perfect → Future) *If I have done it, I will do it again.*
4. (Present → Present perfect) *If I eat pizza, I have also eaten cheese.*
5. (Past → Past) *If I bought anything, I bought that with my own money.*
6. (Past → Past Perfect) *If I did it last year, I had done it perfectly.*
7. (Past Perfect → Past Perfect) *If I had done that, I had done that for you.*
8. (Past Future → Past future) *If I would eat meat, I would not be a vegan anymore.*
9. (Future → Future) *If I will do it, I will do it myself.*
10. (Future → Present) *If I will tell him, I tell him on his face.*

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

How can I classify these conditional sentences into 0th, 1st, 2nd, and 3rd conditionals?

Comment: The first, second, third system of conditionals is like classifying living things as "fish, birds, or animals"  It may be useful for some, but it is neither complete, nor completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I bought anything, I bought that with my own money.

The correct pronoun (?) here is "it", not "that" -- "If ... I bought it with my own money." "That" refers to something specific, and there is no specific thing to refer to.

If I will do it, I will do it myself.

If I will tell him, I tell him on his face.

There is no need for "I will" in either of these sentences (I will do it myself is fine).  "If I do it" and "If I tell him" imply future without any help. The correct preposition in the second sentence is "to", not "on", i.e., "... I will tell him to his face." I think that's idiomatic, i.e., I don't know that there's a grammar rule for it, it's just how it's always said.